# Best Way To Show Formatted Text From SQL on Client?

Tags: javascript, html, sql-server, angularjs

What is the best way to handle formatted text that is saved in SQL but needs to be shown on the client? The original, that is going to be saved in SQL, is in google docs and PDF right now.

I have had two suggestions so far:

1. Just copy and paste the text as is, and then put it in `<pre></pre>` tags. This seems like useless advice, since it's not like I can save tables in a string.
2. Convert to html. Save html in the SQL string, take it to the client, and just show the result.

The second option seems straight-forward enough, but I have no idea what the accepted approach is when doing things like these, so wanted to ask. Also, please let me know the common things to watch out for. For example, it seems some people do something with JSON parse instead of just html.

edit: The document in question is a huge legal document with tables, bullet points, different fonts, etc, etc.

Comment: Google , [`SQL Server Filestream`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thanks, looking at that now, but is there a reason that would be preferable?

Comment: html seems most sensible to me unless you are wanting to open as pdf. Not entirely clear what the higher level issue is

Answer (score 1):

I would reccomend converting the text to html before saving it to the sql server. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/integrate-open#open_and_convert_google_docs_in_your_app) is a link to the google docs api that covers opening and converting a document to html. This might be a good place to start.

Comment: Found a quick version of that here: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/lrtcqJgDEUU

Didn't know you could just download a google doc as html, gotta love it. Wasn't looking forward to messing with converters.

Comment: Indeed. Thank you Google. If the answer helped, please accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but I am waiting to see if there are any other suggestions. I always solve the problem and then come back to accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your use of the text/field is.

1. Document Storage

You can save your PDF documents as blobs in a SQL table, this does not make it easy to modify those documents however.

2. Modifiable text

Copy and pasting text is tedious and very likely to lose formatting, unless you use a WYSIWYG frontend to re-parse the formatting into html (http://ckeditor.com/) or another.

Converting the files directly into html would be 'faster' but also less control over the stored data.

Comment: Thanks, looking over those options now. I just need to show the document. It's an agreement the user accepts before moving to another part of the site, so no modification whatsoever. edit @Jon West: Can you elaborate on the blobs option - just what I need to google. Never heard of that before.